# How to split tables without affecting all stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We have merge replication setup between corporate database and remote clients. Lately we realized that people working on the corporate server do not need data to be tracked by merge replication as this data does not need to flow down to remote clients. We have decided to split tables between remote clients and people working on the corporate server.

Eg: `Table1` has all data for remote clients as well as for people on corporate server. After table splitting, we want it to be `Table1` for remote clients and `Table2` for people on the corporate server.

To accomplish this I will have to change all my stored procedures for inserting and updating records in `table1` and `table2`. First I have to find records in `table1` and in case I don't find records in `table1`, I have to search records in `table2` and then perform crud operations on the record.

Is there any easy way to accomplish this? A way where I don't have to change every stored procedure? I am aware of creating a view over `table1` and `table2`, then create an instead of insert trigger on the view and write logic in trigger to insert into `table1` and `table2`. Is anybody aware of any other way of accomplishing this kind of change?

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something, but instead of splitting tables, have you considered [parameterized filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151318.aspx)?

> Parameterized filters allow different partitions of data to be sent to
>   different Subscribers without requiring multiple publications to be
>   created. For example, a table can be filtered so that **data for a given
>   sales representative is replicated only to that representative.**
>   Parameterized filters have a variety of options that allow you to
>   tailor filtering to optimize performance and best match your data and
>   application requirements. For more information, see Parameterized Row
>   Filters.